# VBA: Highlighting Table Row if Target.Value is found within a column

Tags: vba, events, find, highlight, worksheet

I'm trying to figure out how to highlight the row (A to Q) if the Target.value in another sheet is found in the column. I managed to get to the point that determines if the Target.Value is found in the column within a different sheet, but not sure how to highlight that row in which the Value is found from columns A to Q only. Here is the code I create thus far.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim Lastrow2 As Long
Dim c As Range

Lastrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Lastrow2 = Worksheets("Action Sheet").UsedRange.Rows.Count

Application.EnableEvents = False
For Each c In Target
    If c.Column = 16 Then
    Worksheets("Action Sheet").Cells(Lastrow2 + 1, 1).Value = Target.Value
    End If

Next c
Application.EnableEvents = True

Set Finder = Sheets("BC Contact List").Range("A:A").Find(Target.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
If Not Finder Is Nothing Then

Sheets("BC Contact List").Cells(Finder.Row, 18).Value = "Y"

Sheets("BC Contact List").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(Finder.Row, 1), Cells(Finder.Row, 18)).Select
With Selection.Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 5296274
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there an error? If so what error and what line?

Comment: There is an error in lines -Sheets("BC Contact List").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(Finder.Row, 1), Cells(Finder.Row, 18)).Select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing the error "Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed" would have been helpful in understanding how we could assist. If you know you want columns A:Q colored, just use that overload of the Range method.

`Worksheets("BC Contact List").Range("A" & finder.Row & ":Q" & finder.Row).Select`

The issue with your existing code is the fact that you are attempting to select a range on "BC Contact List" using a reference to the Cells object of the sheet that the Worksheet_Change event has been fired from. Proper way of selecting that range would be (using a Worksheet object for brevity):

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("BC Contact List")
ws.Range(ws.Cells(finder.Row, 1), ws.Cells(finder.Row, 18)).Select
```

Working code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BC Contact List")
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Action Sheet")
    Dim lastRow As Long: lastRow = ws2.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    If (Not (Intersect(Range("P:P"), Target) Is Nothing)) Then

        Dim finder As Range: Set finder = ws1.Range("A:A").Find(Target.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)

        If (Not (finder Is Nothing)) Then
            ws1.Cells(finder.Row, 18).Value = "Y"
            With ws1.Range("A" & finder.Row & ":Q" & finder.Row).Interior
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 5296274
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End If
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

A couple of notes:

- You should always use Option Explicit at the top of your modules (this can be enabled to be automatically inserted in new Modules by going to Tools > Options and clicking Require Variable Declaration. Option Explicit helps ensure you have no typos on variable names.
- I use the ThisWorkbook object rather than ActiveWorksheet/ActiveWorkbook because if you run this by accident from another workbook/worksheet, undesired results will occur.
- I set variables to the Worksheet objects, rather than constantly referring to them with the sheet name. Usually better to use the object than referencing the same thing over and over again (via sheet name, cell number, etc)
- I use the Intersect method to prevent iteration through a large range in Target. Simply put the range you care to see if the Target intersects with, and only do work if it does.
- I removed any Activate and Select/ion calls. These are extremely inefficient when working with large sets of data.

  - One way to improve efficiency is to put `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the beginning of the routine, and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end of the routine (or any exits from a routine)
  - Another is to remove the calls completely. By using the Worksheet objects, we can now interact directly with its members regardless of what sheet or range we're on.

Comment: Very helpful suggestions. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Glad to be of assistance, hope it takes you to your final solution! If you think it answered your question, could you accept this as the answer (and upvote too) so others know?